# Kenmore Electric Stovetop 790 coils not getting red hot

Tags: stove

Can someone tell me how to troubleshoot why on the highest setting the electric coils are getting hot, but not RED hot? The oven is the same. It takes forever to preheat to 350 (~1hr+). I recently did a kitchen remodel and we moved the 240v plug to maybe a foot down the wall. Ever since the move, my electric stovetop does not work the same. I'm not sure if the guys who did the rewiring did it wrong or if there is a problem with the wires inside the stovetop itself.

I am watching [this video,](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vew8pn1t6oM) is there any other resource out there that I can use to figure out this problem?

Comment: your question is like `i drove my car through a bunch of spilled nails and now my tires are flat. Is the problem with the nails, or are the tires defective?`

Comment: Yeah, well I know there must be a way to test the tires first before I look in to the nails.

Comment: Do you have a multimeter?

Comment: I will have a multimeter tomorrow.

Comment: @Anh You say the outlet was moved, Was it moved or a new one installed? What was involved in this rewire job? Did you contact the folks who did the work (*threw the nails in the road*)  to see if they could shed light on what could have changed?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like a bad wiring job. Typical US ovens use 120 for controls and 240 for heating elements. If wired incorrectly you could end up with 120 for the elements and 1/4 the expected power (= heat).

Comment: Easy enough to stick volt meter probes into the receptacle. and measure the voltage..